# Expected Value Question: Conditional Expected vs. Regular

Tags: statistics, probability

You’re drawing 5 coins from a pile of the following: 4 quarters, 2 nickels, 3 dimes. Would you rather draw the 5 coins with or without replacement?

My solution is that it should be same because of linearity of expectation. However, not sure if it applies here.

Comment: you might have better luck (haha) asking on Cross Validated